'Could not set up parent class, due to: Invalid generic instantiation assembly:/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/.../app/Microsoft.Maui.dll
Running .net Maui Hybrid in Visual Studio 2022 .net 8 VS version 17.10.4, xcode 15.4 , Simulator version 17.5.
I am trying to run my application on Windows that compiles ok, is connected OK with the Mac Computer and with the IPhone that is connected on my Mac.

Did you mean the problem only appeared on iOS simulator version 17.5? And you can try to refer this similar issue: iOS application getting crashed "Could not set up parent class, due to: Invalid generic instantiation" .net MAUI.

What is actually question ?

This question is similar to: iOS application getting crashed "Could not set up parent class, due to: Invalid generic instantiation" .net MAUI. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Downgrade CommunityToolkit.Maui from 9.1.0 to 9.0.3

This issue is related with BUG iOS Crash on startup #2158 and it will only happen if you update the CommunityToolkit.Maui from version 9.0.3 to 9.1.0.BTW, have you installed the .NET 9 version and workload?
